# Add a trailing slash to URLs, using Tuckey's URL rewrite filter

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to be able to add a trailing slash to URLs that are missing it (before the parameters). This should be done using this filter : http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

In other words:

- `/web/guest` should become `/web/guest/`
- `/web/guest?` should
  become `/web/guest/?`
- `/web/guest/?` should not be
  altered
- `/web/guest?test=1` should
  become `/web/guest/?test=1`
- `/web/guest/anything/` should not be
  altered

That is easy when the URL has no parameters, but I can't find a matching regex when there are some.

Here's what I could come up with (with exemples and unit tests): https://regex101.com/r/qU3rP3/2:

```
^\/(.+\/[^\/]+?)(\?.*)?$
```

and replacing with `/$1/$2`. It does not yield the expected results.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does `/web/guest/?test=1` seem correct to you ?

Comment: You have not specified expected behavior for `/web/guest/?`. Should it be `/web/guest/?/` or `/web/guest/?`? If second,  try [`([^/?])$|([?][^/]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/nS8yK4/1) to replace with `$1/$2`. If first, [`([^/])$|([?][^/]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/nS8yK4/2)

Comment: @noob yes, this is correct

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew The second solution is the one I want. And your exemple seems to work. Add it in the reply so I can accept it. Thanks !

Comment: By second, you mean [`([^/?])$|([?][^/]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/nS8yK4/1)? Please also update the question with these details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
([^/?])$|/?([?].*)
```

Replace with `$1/$2`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rF7nF6/2).

The pattern contains two alternatives and captures them into Group 1 and 2. Then, in the replacement pattern, we refer to these captured values with `$1` and `$2` backreferences.

Details:

- `([^/?])$` - match and capture into Group 1 any character but a `/` or `?` at the end of the string
- `|` - or
- `/?` - an optional (1 or 0) forward slash
- `([?].+)` - match and capture into Group 2 a literal `?` followed with 1+ characters other than a newline

The replacement works even in case one capture group is empty because a non-participating capture group is filled with an empty string after a match.

Comment: I re-checked and it seems to me the pattern should be [`([^/?])$|/?([?].*)`](https://regex101.com/r/rF7nF6/2). Please confirm.

Comment: You're actually right. Didn't notice the mistake. Thanks for double checking it !

Comment: Good. The `/` was doubled since the slash is in the replacement pattern. In order not to double it, the `/` should also be matched but not *captured* so as not to add an existing one. If there are multiple consecutive slashes in the URLs you get, you can replace `/?` with `/*` in the pattern (`*` matches 0 or more times).